# How to set maximum time to wait for mongodb connection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, timeout

I'm trying to send back an error to the client if the database couldn't connect after 3 seconds.
I have came across those ways from the mongoose docs.

1)

```
  mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/smslist?connectTimeoutMS=1000"
```

2) setting this option :

```
connectTimeoutMS: 1000
```

I have closed the server in order to make sure that it does not respond, I expected the client to receive an error after one second but unfortunately both of those did not work, and the client receives an error only after 30 seconds which is the default for node sockets as far as I know. Do you have any clue how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone comes across this post, I have fixed it by using `serverSelectionTimeoutMS=1000` instead of `connectTimeoutMS=1000`